# Bootstrap navbar using Marionette

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, marionette

I've been trying to display a bootstrap navbar using Marionette with no success. I took one of the example navbar with a divider and drop-down. Following is the html I'm trying to display using Marionette.

I extended the region class of marionette to append the left and right nav elements as separate views. How can I display something like this esp the divder etc. Can someone please suggest an approach?

```
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li class="active"><a href="./">Default</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
        <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
    </ul>
</div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To render some html you should use [one of Marionette view](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette#marionettes-pieces) instead of region. Purpose of [Marionette.Region](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md) is not rendering some HTML but representing place in which you can insert some other view.

If you need render static html you can use `Marionette.ItemView`.
Here is [example](http://jsbin.com/hiruveze/1/edit?html,output)

But if you want create navbar dynamically you should use more complex solution with models, collection and more complex view.

Comment: @user3261334 Please mark his answer as the answer :)